# request.setcharacterencoding() method seems do nothing in the source code

Tags: java, http, servlets, jakarta-ee, request

In a servlet java class,I type **request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8")**, and then I want to see what this method actually is in the source code,and I use CTRL+LEFT-CLICK to enter the method's source code
And then it goes to the **ServletRequest Interface**, in the Interface the method's code is

```
public void setCharacterEncoding(String env)
    throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
```

It's surely an empty method because `ServletRequest` is an Interface.

Where can I see what this method actually have done to set the encoding?

Comment: I suggest using the debugger and setting a breakpoint, then using "step into" to jump into the implementing class. As far as I know the "real" class will be provided by the servlet container such as tomcat, jetty etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is implemented by servlet container. For example for Tomcat 8.5 implementation reside in 
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request#setCharacterEncoding
and looks like:

```
public void setCharacterEncoding(String enc) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if(!this.usingReader) {
            B2CConverter.getCharset(enc);
            this.coyoteRequest.setCharacterEncoding(enc);
        }
    }
```

As you can see it is just validates encoding name and set internal request implementation field in which encoding stored. You can search you servlet container source code for `implements HttpServletRequest` and look at implementation.